# Getting wrong element using directive in Primeng p-table

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the new p-table component of primeng. My first column is frozen and contains three buttons each row The other columns are dynamically generated and simple text outputs. Primeng generates the header, body and the frozen column in an own html table. If I click on a button in the frozen column I want to get the whole row via a directive `#tableCol` (not sure if its a directive) of my table and highlight it but I only get the frozen column row.
The highlighting occurs in the `rowDeletionMark(tableCol)` method.

How could get the row in the "main" table where the actual data/rows are?

My primeng table:

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="header" [value]="data" [resizableColumns]="true" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [paginator]="true"
    [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]" sortMode="multiple" [reorderableColumns]="true" class="ptable row-cancel"
    [scrollable]="true" frozenWidth="150px">
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
      <colgroup>
        <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:200px">
      </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:150px;font-size:13px" pResizableColumn pReorderableColumn 
          [pSortableColumn]="col.field !== 'ACTION' ? col.field : null">
          {{col.field}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      <tr>
        <td #tableCol *ngFor="let col of columns" height="48" style="width:150px;padding:0 5px 0 5px;line-height: 1;" [ngStyle]="getRowMarking(rowData)"
          pEditableColumn>
          <div *ngIf="col.field === 'ACTION'">
            <button pButton type="button" class="row-btn" icon="fa fa-fw fa-save"></button>
            <button pButton type="button" class="row-btn ui-button-danger" icon="fa fa-fw fa-eraser" (click)="rowDeletionMark(tableCol)"></button>
            <button pButton type="button" class="row-btn ui-button-info" icon="far fa-clock-o" (click)="showRowHistory(rowData)"></button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="col.editable && col.field !== 'ACTION'">
            <p-cellEditor>
              <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data[col.field]">
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
              </ng-template>
            </p-cellEditor>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="!col.editable">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

highlight method:

```
rowDeletionMark(tableCol) {
    tableCol.className += ' canceled';
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a Plunker please ?